# How to write this perticular command without echo concatenation?

Tags: java, terminal, echo, processbuilder, moses

I am using this command as given in the tutorial here
http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.Baseline

```
echo 'T W O N E I G H T' | /home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini
```

It is working fine and correctly but I need to run it without echo command. Because I wanted to run this command in JAVA (Eclipse) and there is problem with concatenation. Even

```
      Process p = r.exec("echo '/home/saj/' | ls");
```

is also not running. Though simple commmands like ls,pwd are working correctly.

I tried these things but none of them is working..

/home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini 'T W O N E I G H T'

/home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini T W O N E I G H T

/home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses 'T W O N E I G H T' -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini

/home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses T W O N E I G H T -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini

Please suggest correct command to run without echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your arguments contain spaces, you cannot rely on the built-in tokenization. To avoid this, use `exec(String[])` rather than `exec(String)`. For example, for this command:

```
/home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses -f \
    /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini 'T W O N E I G H T'
```

You would do this:

```
String args[] = new String[] {
    "/home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses",
    "-f",
    "/home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini",
    "T W O N E I G H T" };
Process p = r.exec(args);
```

Also, regarding piping and redirection, note that these are handled by the shell. In order to run a command line such as `echo '/home/saj/' | ls` from Java, you should execute a shell and pass this to the shell as an argument; for example:

```
String args[] = new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo '/home/saj/' | ls" };
Process p = r.exec(args);
```